# Make arraylist of questions, options and answres in java android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to java programing and i need to make an arraylist which will store questions, options and answres. What is the best way to do that if I want to use that arraylist for questions with 4 options and also for questions with multiple choices and questions with typed answer by user.

My text file with questions looks like this:

```
Which Java keyword is used to define a subclass?
extends

What is the original name of the Java language?
A) Swift
B) C--
C) Oak
D) Ruby
C

Which of the following types are supertypes of Rectangle?
A) PrintStream
B) Shape
C) RectangularShape
D) Object
BCD
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you saying you want to parse the text file and store the questions and answers in ArrayLists?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i am asking.

Comment: OK, do you want an ArrayList of Question-Option-Answer combination, or three ArrayLists for each? Either way, you probably would like to create a class to encompass your custom data structure. How about you present those first, and then the question can be focused on the "parsing from text" part, which I guess is the core problem?

Comment: ArrayList for each would be better because later I need to shuffle questions and options. Well, i don't understand how to make a class for that. Like I said, I am completly beginner in java programing.

Comment: Then you need to read some Java tutorial and have some foundational understanding before moving on to this task, which is I believe not the best starting point for beginners.

Comment: Will be easier if you separate the questions into files, qhere each file contains single or multiple coice questions. Otherwise, how do you know whether a question is multiple choice ir not? Will be more complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should receate a model for that. A model is a data class.

```
class QuestionModel() {
    String question;
    String singleAnswer;
    List<String> listSingleChoiceAnswer;
    List<String> listMultipleChoiceAnswer;

public QuestionModel(
    String singleAnswer, 
    List<String> listSingleChoiceAnswer,
    List<String> listMultipleChoiceAnswer
) {
    this.singleAnswer = singleAnswer;
    this.listSingleChoiceAnswer = listSingleChoiceAnswer;
    this.listMultipleChoiceAnswer = listMultipleChoiceAnswer;
}
}
```

Then, when you want to create a list question

`Arraylist<QuestionModel> listQuestion = new Arraylist<QuestionModel>;`

Ex, you want to add a typeable answer question

`listQuestion.add(new QuestionModel("Which Java keyword is used to define a subclass?", "extends", null, null))`

or a multiple choice

```
Arraylist<String> multipleAns = Arraylist<String>("A","B","C","D")
listQuestion.add(new QuestionModel("Which of the following types are supertypes of Rectangle?", null, null, multipleAns))
```

Finally you can display questions depend on not NULL type answer.